# I want some specific text when the age is below 12

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to have a specific text if the typed age is below 12 years old. I thought of some covert to int, in some kind of way. But i can't figure out how. Can someone help me out?

This is what i have:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" onclick="btnSend_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Literal ID="litResult" runat="server" />
```

This is my code-behind:

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtAge.Text <= 12)
    {
        litResult.Text = "You are a child";
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Text` property of a `TextBox` is a string, so you need to convert the age to an `int`.

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int age;
    if (int.TryParse(txtAge.Text, out age));
    {
        if (age <= 12)
            litResult.Text = "You are a child";
    }
    else
        litResult.Text = "Please enter a valid age";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to cast the txtAge.Text into an integer then do it.

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int age = -2;
        try
        {
            age = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);

            if (age <= 12)
            {
                litResult.Text = "You are a child";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            litResult.Text = "Entered values is not a number ";
        }
    }
```